# Remove last two slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I need to remove the last two slides of my slick slider on a specific browser width.

I thought:

```
$('.slider').slick('slickRemove', slideIndex - 1);
```

would do it at least for the last. But I was wrong.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/osywsskz/

..

If I pick a specific slide number:

```
$('.slider').slick('slickRemove',4);
```

it works. But the number of slides varies, so this is no solution

Comment: The `slideIndex` is not defined at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get slide count:

```
$(".slider").slick({
  autoplay: false,
  dots: true,
});

$(document).ready(function(){

  var docWidth = $(document).width();    

  function getLastSlide(){
    return ($(".slider").slick("getSlick").slideCount - 1);
  }

  var deleteCount = 2;

  if(docWidth>500 && docWidth<700 )
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < deleteCount; i++) {
      $('.slider').slick('slickRemove', getLastSlide());
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: oh my god magic :D - thank you! and how can I delete the last two and not just the last one?

Comment: And is there a better way to combine further breakpoints than this: https://jsfiddle.net/cyhosusx/ ?

Comment: @MaxDiCampo I updated my post. I think my method is better and shortly, because you only need to specify the number of pictures in a variable `deleteCount`.

Comment: Yes, already checking and trying to understand it. And how do I combine this in a smart and clean way with several breakpoints and several deleteCounts? So eg between 500 and 700 delete the last two, between 700 and 900 delete the last 3 - see my last comment fiddle fail :D

Comment: @MaxDiCampo All you need is to call `deleteSlide` with the count, fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/osywsskz/2/

Comment: No! Magic! I did it like https://jsfiddle.net/qjs1Lq8b/ - but yours is way better! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MaxDiCampo Good luck :) You can upvote or "accepted" answer, I will appreceate.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from [the github page of slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/):

> slickRemove
>   index, removeBefore
>   Remove slide by index. If removeBefore
>   is set true, remove slide preceding index, or the first slide if no
>   index is specified. **If removeBefore is set to false, remove the slide
>   following index, or the last slide if no index is set.**

So `$('.slider').slick('slickRemove', false);` does the trick!
See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ufomhmz/

Comment: thanks, but here we are at my knowledge boundaries :D - I really don't know how to do that. :O Could you give me a hint?

Comment: You can use the solution provided by @SteveB ofcourse but this looks alot cleaner, and is also the directly supported API of slick.js.

Comment: I am looking for the cleanest solution. In your example, how do I delete the last two and not just the last?

Comment: Ah I forgot you wanted to remove the last 2. Well you could simply call it twice I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define slideIndex as the count of slides. That can be done as follows

```
var slideIndex = $(".slider > *").length
```

If you want to remove the last two slides, the following code will work (not the most elegant)

```
$('.slider').slick('slickRemove', slideIndex);
$('.slider').slick('slickRemove', slideIndex - 1);
```

All of this is inside your if statement so the final code looks like this

```
   var docWidth = $( document ).width();    

if(docWidth>500 && docWidth<700 )
{
  var slideIndex = $(".slider > *").length
  $('.slider').slick('slickRemove', slideIndex);
  $('.slider').slick('slickRemove', slideIndex - 1);
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is working! For everybody else looking for the solution, here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wxspsn35/

Comment: Sorry, further question. How do I combine this with several breakpoints? So eg. between 500-700 delete the last two. between 701 and 1000 just delete the last. I tried but failed: https://jsfiddle.net/d4k5z2zh/

Comment: The code I provided uses two lines to delete the last two indexes. If you just want to delete the last index, remove the line that says slideIndex -1 (last line in the if statement) . As noted below, there are better ways to handle this then deleting the slides, you can set the amount of slides to show and let the user scroll through the rest.